# Redirect to the same form with data loaded - Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla

I have overridden the SAVE() function in Joomla 2.5

```
class footballModelPlayer extends JModelAdmin {

public function getTable($type = 'Player', $prefix = 'footballTable', $config = array()) {
    return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
}

public function save($data) {
   // some code here
  $table_one->bind($data);
  $table_one->save($data);
    return true;
}
```

Problem is the when I save the new data or edit the existing one, it redirects me to the New Empty From.

If I replace last line by `return $data->player_id` it redirects me to the same form loaded with data but show error

```
Save failed with the following error:
```

Hoe can I save/update the records with displaying Successful Message and staying on the same form with data loaded into it???

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 functions in  your model:

```
public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true){
    // Get the form.
    $form = $this->loadForm('com_football.Player', 'Player', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
    if (empty($form)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $form;

 }
```

and

```
protected function loadFormData(){
    $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_football.edit.Player.data', array());
    if (empty($data)) 
    {
        $data = $this->getItem();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Implement them and your data will magically appear. You don't need to override the save method by the way, since you are doing what will be done by default.

Comment: I already had those functions in my file ... I just omitted to post in my question ... 

And solution to my problem got solved by

return parent::save();